# Value of null in double should print 0

Tags: java

I have a small doubt that I couldn't get around with that is I have a double variable which stores double value but I want it to print 0 instead of 0.0 when it has no data but whatever I try I couldn't make it work
 for example:

```
double a = 0;
System.out.println(a);
```

should give me **0** instead of **0.0**

I know it's a silly question but can anyone point me in the right direction, 
thank you in advance.

Comment: When it's null? Primitives can't be null.

Comment: `double` is a decimal type, if you don't want the decimal value use `int`

Comment: My value is of a decimal type it always gives me a value but when it doesn't it prints **0.0** but I want it to print as **0**

Comment: You need to use int instead of double

Comment: So you basically want a special behavior if a certain case happens. Why not create an `if`-statement? Like `String toPrint; if ( ...) { toPrint = "0"; } else { toPrint = ... }`. You should always try to separate your pure logic from stuff like how you want to display it in the end. A basic concept, often called **formatting** in this situation. Take a look at the answer of @mathur, he's showing something like that.

Comment: Do you want to keep a decimal representation for values different to `0.0`? So should it show `4.0` or `4` for example?

Comment: yes, it should happen only when the value is 0 and I did try writing a formatter But I don't want the value to be in String representation as I'm trying this to make a JSON string and I don't want "0" Quotes around 0 in the json

Comment: Which methods are you using in the end to add your data to your JSON stuff? Can you show us this code? A `String` itself doesn't contain quotes `"` and the method `System.out.println(...)` converts every argument to `String` first. So the `0.0` comes because the method converts the `double` to `String` and this is the regular `String` representation. It could however be possible that your JSON formatter adds quotes on its own, that's why I'm asking. In that case your question is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm Using GSON to add my data and convert it to JSON. As you said it'll convert it into a string but if the variable holding the value is not a string then it'll not add quotes **''**  .

Comment: So It prints it as 0.0 not "0.0". I tried Type casting the value and even created a **formatter** as mathur suggested before but for some reason, it's still printing it as 0.0. basically, I get a data for example  `double data = 1.475`  then this data is passed to Gson along with other fields and then using **Gson's toJson()** I'm printing it as a JSON string. So here the variable is double so it considers it as a numeric value and quotes `"` are not added it prints it as `data: 1.475` . In the same way, when the data is **0** it's printing it as `data: 0.0`

Comment: Now come to think of it I think the variable that's storing the data is double and even though we typecast it still holds the value in double so it won't change 0 to 0.0 ``double a = (int) 1.475 ` . My problem might be associated with the Json. I need a way to typecast the value in the Json if there is no data available for that single variable. I'm using a hashmap to hold the fields and passing the hashmap to the Gson to print it as Json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163764/discussion-between-srikar-and-zabuza).

Comment: Instead of commenting you might **edit** your question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use some method as shown below:

```
double a = 0.0;
System.out.println(formatA(a));

static String formatA(double a) {
    if (a == 0.0)
        return "0";
    else
        return String.valueOf(a);
}
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Why not? I like this approach, separates the data itself from the representation. Formatting is a basic concept.

Comment: @Zabuza I would just cast that value or use `"%.0f"`, that's much cleaner

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Mh, not if OP wants to keep the decimal representation in any other case than `a == 0.0`. But yeah, formatting with a formatting pattern is an option too. Imo this answer is a nice showcase for how basic things can be done, I'm sure it will help OP.

Comment: @Zabuza casting a float to int in `PrintStream` won't change its type. And about the formatting `"%.0f"`, it's not an option but a better option than creating a separate method.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat appreciate your comment but if you use `%.0f` formatting then every other value than 0.0 will also be affected. e.g. 5.4 will print 5. The question was specific for 0.0 value.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast type of variable 'a' to an integer.

```
double a = 0;
System.out.println((int)a);
```

Comment: I did try to typecast the variable but it's not working

Comment: @Srikar Then you didn't cast it correctly. By using the code of @SafvanCK it will print `0` and not `0.0`. Printing an `int` will never show a decimal point, integers are no decimal values.

Comment: @Zabuza No doubt ;)

Answer (score 0):

man, `double a = 0;` is a decimal type. you'd make:

change the type of the value

```
int a = 0
```

Or, also you can cast the value.

```
System.out.println((int) a);
```

Comment: *also you can use intValue from the Double type*, umm OP has `double`, not `Double`

Comment: yes, you are right. in that case, he can cast it, `(int) a`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the fractional part of the double value, you can cast it into long value. 
Note, it's not a good idea to cast it into "int" value, because max "double" value is greater than max "int" value.

```
double a = 0;
System.out.println((long)a);
```